# Unity 2D. Передвижение предметов курсором

Tags: unity3d, mouse-event, obj, move

Хочу узнать как осуществить передвижение предмета за курсором (когда мышка зажата на предмете). Мало того, мне еще нужно чтобы только определенный предмет можно было перетаскивать, как сделать условие проверяющее это, и вообще как написать метод OnMouseDown? Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете 2d пространство (2d игра или canvas), то существуют интерфейсы [IBeginDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.html), [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html), [IEndDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEndDragHandler.html)

Подскажу, что в методе `OnDrag(EventData eventData)` есть переменная `eventData` и с помощью неё можно передвигать объект на который упал луч (тут вам самим пускать луч не нужно).

Для того что бы перемещать объект за курсором мыши нужно написать

`eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;`

Answer (score 1):

Для начала как определить какой то объект. 
Тут вам стоит почитать как бросать лучи. 
Вот пример луча который бросается с положения мышки.

`If(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))`

Из названия метода понятно что он отвечает за нажатие на кнопку мышки.  Индекс в параметрах отвечает за какую именно кнопку:

- 0 левая кнопка мышки
- 1 правая кнопка мыши
- 2 вроде бы колесико

Что бы бросить луч вам нужно объявить переменную луча.

`Ray ray;`

А теперь конвертируем точку экрана в луч.

`ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition));`

Теперь вам нужен результат пересечения луча.

`RaycastHit hit;`

Теперь запускаем созданный выше луч.

`If(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))`

Если лучше был брошен то это условие сработает. 
А дальше переменная `hit` хранит в себе данные от столкновение с чем то. 
К примеру можно получить объект с которым он пересекся.

`hit.collider.gameObject`

И с этим уже можно делать  что угодно. 
Так как вы хотите тащить объект за мышкой то вам нужно  поместить весь выше описанный код в условие:

`if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))`

Это условие отвечает за то что кнопка мышки зажата. 
Так же бросаем луч что бы определять что мы движемся тот же объект. 
Ну и соответственно перемешать его как захотите. 
Можно оптимизировать уменьшив количество лучей дополнительными условиями. Простор для действий огромный. Но суть такая же.

Comment: Будьте добры, форматируйте свои ответы, это невозможно читать.

Comment: С удовольствием, но так как писал это с телефона, то это было проблематично

Comment: ИМХО лучше уж "дотерпеть" до пк, чем выдавать хоть и правильный, но нечитабельный ответ :)

Comment: Я напомню что я работаю не с UI а со спрайтами, и код должен быть для 2D. Ни один ответ не помог :(

Comment: Чтобы облегчить себе жизнь и находить только требуемые объекты вы можете назначить объектам отдельный слой и искать по маске слоя https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html а сама `LayerMask` можете сделать отдельной переменной в скрипте который рейкастит, чтобы было удобно настраивать

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour {

    private Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

        offset = gameObject.transform.position -
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10.0f));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10.0f);
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newPosition) + offset;
    }
}
```

просто вешаешь скрипт на обьект.
Ответ взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38407823/4423545